# Calling Javascript from Controller in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In UI:

1) I have to check the ComboBox
2) As HTTPGET send the selected value of ComboBox
3) Then Uncheck the ComboBox, after execution of Controller Action Method.

Code:

```
 $("#Search").click(function () {
        $(".selsts").attr('checked', false);
    });
```

This is my JQuery to uncheck the ComboBox On Button Click "Search".

Problem:

Before sending the Value to the controller Action, 
the checkbox get Unchecked and hence I am not receiving the CheckBox Value.

```
  @using (@Html.BeginForm("GetExtMsg", "ShowMessage", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div id="inputFields">
        <div class="inputLabel"><label><b>Search By:</b></label> </div>
    </div>


    @Html.CheckBox("Review", new { @class="selsts" })
    <label style="float: left;">Review Status</label>

    @Html.CheckBox("Corellation", new { @class = "selsts" })
    <label style="float: left;">Corellation</label>

    @Html.CheckBox("ControllerStatus", new { @class = "selsts" })
    <label style="float: left;">Controllers</label>

    @Html.CheckBox("Team", new { @class = "selsts" })
    <label style="float: left;">Team</label>

    @Html.DropDownList("ReviewsearchType", new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Reviewed", Value = "Reviewed" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Review Done", Value = "Review Done" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Authorized", Value = "Authorized" }
        }, "Select")
    @Html.DropDownList("CorellationsearchType", new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "A", Value = "A" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "B", Value = "B" },
        }, "Select")
    @Html.DropDownList("ControllersearchType", new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "True", Value = "True" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "False", Value = "False" },
        }, "Select")
    <input type="submit" id="Search" value="Search" class="button_gray" />
}
```

**JavaScript :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#ReviewsearchType').hide();
    $("#Review").change(function () {
        $('#ReviewsearchType').toggle(this.checked)
    })

    $('#CorellationsearchType').hide();
    $("#Corellation").change(function () {
        $('#CorellationsearchType').toggle(this.checked)
    });

    $('#ControllersearchType').hide();
    $("#ControllerStatus").change(function () {
        $('#ControllersearchType').toggle(this.checked)
    })

    $("#Search").click(function () {
        $(".selsts").attr('checked', false);
    });


});
```

Any Suggessions/Help?

Comment: If the user surfs to the page, the checkbox is always checked? Then you can just check it by default in the HTML.

Comment: for the first time after Page Load, The checkboxes are unchecked.

Comment: Unless you explicitly check them in HTML.

Comment: How to do it? I am not getting you.

Comment: Post more code, is this a full submit or is it an ajax call?

Comment: your question is not clear..as far as i interpreted...do you want selected checkbox  in controller?

Comment: Yes Kamlesh, But After getting the selected Checkbox and after the execution of the ActionMethod, I want the checkbox to be UnChecked.

Comment: either unchecked them in your controller or while page load..iterate over all checkboxes and set their checked property to false

Comment: @avidenic , This is a full submit.

Comment: Thanks Kamlesh, But how to unchecked them in controller?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, click event fires before submit event, so you are unchecking your check-box with this code:

```
$("#Search").click(function () {
    $(".selsts").attr('checked', false);
});
```

That is why you are not getting the values to the server. Make the default state of checkbox "unchecked".

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

this will cause it to be unchecked by default, when page reloads after submit.

EDIT: full submit will usually reload the page, show me your controller code as well please. If you want to preserve the state of UI before submit you have several options:

- return data that was submitted with response and use MVCs "Model" to fill in the values
- save data before submit somewhere (local storage, session, whatever)
- do not do a full submit, but use ajax to query the API and display results

Comment: I have made default unchecked But after checking it still it is maintaing its state and after postback, its remains unchecked.

Comment: @user3615920 I've edited my answer, please add controller code as well